# Should we always return by ref if we can?

Tags: c#, optimization, ref, c#-7.0, c#-7.2

Now with C# 7, we can return by ref with `return ref`. From what I've gathered, references are 32 or 64 bits. Now, if I had a struct `Coord` with a `long X` and `long Y`, that would be 128 bits, so it'd be easier return the coord, (as well as pass it) by reference to avoid copying the 128 bits.

On the other hand, if I were to try to `return ref` a `byte`, which is only 8 bits, the reference to it would be much larger than copying byte itself, right?

So, my main question: **If the object we want to return can be returned by `ref` (ie, not a local variable) and its size is larger than the size of a reference, should we return by `ref`?**

**Edit:** Quick code example

```
// This size is 128 bytes, which is 2 or 4x larger than the size of a reference
public struct Coord                                 
{
    public long X, Y;
}

private Coord myCoord;

// This will return the Coord by value, meaning copying the full 128 bytes
public Coord GetCoordValue() => myCoord;          

// This will return the Coord by reference, meaning copying only 32 or 64 bytes
public ref readonly Coord GetCoordRef() => ref myCoord;
```

Also, this particular struct is very simple and it's already 2/4x smaller to return by `ref`.

**Edit 2:** I made `GetCoordRef()` `readonly` so that the caller can't save and change the value of `myCoord`, thereby preserving encapsulation, though I imagine this still wouldn't be smart to default to using it.

Comment: Size isn't everything. Indirection costs, too. It's an obvious win if your structs are very large and often copied. It's no longer as obvious if your structs are only modestly sized and/or not as often copied. Like *anything* intended to help with performance, doing it reflexively without a solid framework for profiling your actual performance is not a good idea.

Comment: It's better to provide a code example to clarify your point.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/05/03/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/

Comment: You can't `ref return` something unless it is *safe* to `ref return`; you certainly can't `ref return` from your method's stack space (locals). There are *scenarios* where `ref return` is a life-saver, but it isn't part of routine work

Comment: With your example one can do `c.GetCoordRef() = new Coord() { X = 1, Y = 2 };`. Are you always fine to allow that? I doubt.

Comment: Your code example is effectively the same as making the field `public`. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @Adrian And of course if you *do* want to make it public then *just make it public* rather than creating a method just to return a reference to it.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think of that, @Evkm. I can see how that'd make this a dangerous practice to default to, as it removes all encapsulation

Comment: @Adrian Especially true if this was a property instead of a method. It's giving the caller direct access to the private field, which defeats the entire point about it being private.

Comment: Note that there are also ref readonly returns: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md. which semantics are closer to what you expect.

Comment: No, this is not a good idea.  Intuitively, if it were then they would have just changed the compiler to do it automatically.  But they did not know how to do it and required your help to get it right.  Which is hard work, you can spend many hours on profiling the differences and changing classes to structs, avoiding having the test results being too much affected by the test.  C# did not exactly get any prettier from this addition, the bigger reason it took so long to get added.

Comment: @Evk, You're right. After making that change, `myCoord` is no longer effectively public, but imagine that it's still not good practice to default to using `ref readonly`, correct?

Comment: @AustinWBryan yes, for example because access via reference is slower that direct access. In high perfomance applications (that's where you will use such features anyway) that might matter quite a lot.

Comment: @Evk So accessing by reference is slower, even though it uses and copies less bytes, or did I read that the wrong way?

Comment: Oh no, we've become C++. I use C# so I don't have to think about this kind of stuff....

Comment: C++ being my first language, I'm glad this has been added. I don't think it's anything to be afraid of though; you don't have to use it. It's like when C# added `dynamic` and `var` and I was afraid it was becoming JavaScript or Python, but `var` is just sugar that I've come to love, and I've never once seen `dynamic` actually used.

If you don't want to use it then don't, but that doesn't mean that the developers that *do* want use it, shouldn't have the option. Part of what makes C# great is that it keeps adding stuff from other languages, expanding what it can do.

Comment: I mean, suppose you _access_ (say, read) that variable you got from GetCoordRef in a tight loop. It points to myCoords field, which is a member of a class (I assume) and so is on heap. It might be somewhat slower compared to accessing variable obtained by GetCoordValue (which is local variable and is on stack), for example because it can be proven that local variable cannot be changed and it can be cached in CPU register.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If the object we want to return can be returned by ref (ie, not a local variable) and its size is larger than the size of a reference, should we return by ref?

(1) No.

(2) For advanced users only: yes, **in precisely those cases where your empirical, accurate profiling data indicates that making this change transforms your program from one that disappoints users into one that delights users**.

Are there programs in the marketplace whose failure or success can be traced back to the couple nanoseconds difference of copying a couple extra bytes being traded for the couple nanoseconds of making a pointer indirection later?  I'm not aware of any, but maybe you write programs whose users have very tight budgets for the number of nanoseconds they want  your API to take.